# Reactjs and Flexbox: Wrapping divs in render function making flex hard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

React is getting me in trouble with flexbox because of the wrapping div in a component's render function is throwing off my flex-directions.

From what I understand about React, all the component's jsx elements should be wrapped up in a single div. For example this works:

```
return (
    <div className="com-container">
       <div className="other-stuff">
       </div>
    </div>
)
```

whereas this doesn't:

```
return (
    <div className="com-container">
    </div>
    <div className="other-stuff">
    </div>
)
```

Yet this is making things hard with flexbox rows and columns. For example say we had this flex relationship.

```
<Parent Column Component /> //vertical flex
  <ChildRowComponent1 />    //horizontal flex
  <ChildRowComponent2 />    //horizontal flex
  <ChildRowComponent3 />    //horizontal flex
```

But `ChildRowComponent2` & `3` can be swapped out dynamically - which causes me to refactor by putting `ChildRowComponent2` & `3` in their own component but since all rendering must be wrapped up in a single div I get this extra div that messes up the flex directions.

```
<Parent Column Component />  //vertical flex
  <ChildRowComponent1 />     //horizontal flex
  <div>                      
    <ChildRowComponent2 />   //horizontal flex now broken
    <ChildRowComponent3 />   //horizontal flex now broken
  </div>
```

### Question:

Is there a flexbox trick to handle these cases or am I just doing something  wrong with how I'm structuring my components?

Comment: This is a known problem, [see this report on github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127) - sadly no easy fix yet.

Comment: Great editing @m01! Helped capture the problem very well!

Answer (score 2):

Fragments solve this problem. You don't need any extra `<div>` elements when wrapping child elements. This won't add extra nodes to the DOM.

```
return (
 <React.Fragment>
    <div className="com-container">
    </div>
    <div className="other-stuff">
    </div>
 <React.Fragment>
)
```

[React Fragment Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a component that groups `ChildRowComponent2` & `3`, you can make it a function that returns a list. Then you can do this in your `Parent` component:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main-container">
        <ChildRowComponent1 />
        { this.renderOtherChildren() }
      </div>
    )
  },
  renderOtherChildren: function () {
    var result = [];
    if (this.props.shouldHaveSecondChild) {
      result.push(<ChildRowComponent2 key={ 2 } />);
    }
    if (this.props.shouldHaveThirdChild) {
      result.push(<ChildRowComponent3 key={ 3 } />);
    }
    return result;
  },
```

If you're wondering why do you need the `key` prop, [here is an explanation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children).

Comment: I'll experiment with this and let you know how it goes. Open to any other workarounds people have come up with.

Comment: Also @m01, could you elaborate on your answer just a little more? I've never seen another function that is potentially returning jsx, or other components, so seeing the syntax of that would be quite useful.

Comment: I added this to the answer.

Comment: I'm reading the link you posted now. I'll try it out and let everyone know how it turned out :)

Comment: One last clarifying question- this.props.children will change with routing so it's value, for example, could either be <LandingPageRowComponent /> or <ChildRowComponent2><ChildRowComponent3>. How could we check for the routing cases in your renderOtherChildren method?

Comment: Well, I think that you could actually refactor your router so that instead of rendering the components, it would just *return the information* about which components should be visible. Then your `Parent` component would get this information in `props` and handle accordingly. (Disclaimer: I never used react-router.)

Btw: `this.props.children` is a list (e.g. `[<ChildRowComponent2>, <ChildRowComponent3>]`), so you can use it as you would use the output from my `renderOtherChildren` function.